# Forms with a tumblr site and running scripts on a tumblr site

Tags: html, forms, dns, tumblr

1 ) On Tumblr is it possible to create a form and / or at the very least program. If I want to write a shell script, or a python script, can I do that? Note that we have domain space from GoDaddy[ to my chagrin =( I had no say in that ]. Perhaps there is a way to use tumblr for most of the front end but be able to do database stuff, and all sorts of other fun stuff?

EDIT: IF there are any better work arounds I absolutely need to know!

Comment: if you are gonna downvote please explain! (=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tumblr won't give you any form of database or backend processing beyond what you can get with the usual functionality.  However if you've got hosting elsewhere you could certainly  create a form that posts to a different domain (i.e. your godaddy site)

```
<form action="http://yourgodaddydomain/someendpoint">
    <!-- form -->
</form>
```

You could then set the endpoint (python script, php, whatever) to redirect back to your tumblr site.

Comment: I shouldn't need a redirect if the x.tumblr automatically redirects to x.com, yeah? also thank you for throwing me a bone!

Comment: Submitting the from will redirect you to your godaddy site, however if you then want to send the user back to the page they were on, you would need to redirect them back, if you've happy form them to stay on your other site then that's fine.

Comment: Alternatively you could post the data with javascript and the user would stay on the same page, but then you have some fun and games with the single origin policy, as browsers don't really like javascript talking between different domains, but a bit of googling should reveal some workarounds.